# How to solve limits for trigonometric sequences? $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^3\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

What kind of criteria do I have to use to solve for trigonometric limits.

For Example those kind of problems:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^3\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

or

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin(n+2)\sin(n-2)}{\cos(n+2)\cos(n-2)}$$

I obviously can't get there with the sandwich-theorem or the ratio test.

Thanks for help community.

Comment: There is always the chance to apply L' Hospitals rule. That wold work for the upper limit. However one does not learn too much using L'Hospital, that's why I am kinda against this method. Maybe there is another way..

For the lower limit, you should ask, whether the limit is well defined.

Comment: Multiply rop and bottom by $1+\cos(1/n)$ and let $1/n=t$. Now it's nearly over.

Comment: So I am allowed to use hopiâl for sequences as well? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, use double angle formula: $\cos 2A=1-2\sin^2 A$,   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(1-1+2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}\right)^2\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(1)^2(1)=\color{red}{\frac 12}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I don't see how you let the $n^3$ go  $n/2$ though?

Comment: Alright, notice in third step $n^3$ changes to $\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}$ & $n/2$ is left in numerator

Comment: Which trigonometric equality to you use? $x^3 = ?$ I'm sorry I still don't see it. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I have already shown the trig identity of double angle to use is $\cos 2A=1-2\sin^2 A$

Comment: Yeah I see that, I don't see why this would impact $n^3$

Comment: Good question, it is because $(1-\cos (1/n))$ will change in square term $2\sin^2(1/2n)$ that will take $n^2$ & rest $n$ is distributed to $\sin(1/n)$ Thus $n^3$ term is distributed in two separate  limits as shown in the answer

Comment: What is the formal name for those kind of distributions? I've never heard that you can turn $n^x$ into trigonometric functions.

Comment: it's just separation of terms to split a given limit into two or more existing limits. That's all

Comment: Sorry I had a hanger there, maxes sense $n^3 = 1/1/n^3$ and afterwards you'd apply hopital

Comment: yes, you can also apply l'hopital rule to find limit or you should know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, set $1/n=2h$  to get

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1-\cos2h)\sin2h}{(2h)^3}=\dfrac12\cdot\left(\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h\right)^2\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin2h}{2h}$$

Comment: I don't see where this is going yet. Why are you taking the limit to 0 and not to infinity?

Comment: because $1/n=2h$ so that when $n \to \infty$, so does $h \to 0$

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. How do you get from the first step to the second one?

Comment: @Fill, Use $$\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use series approximations. For example,

$$1 - \cos x = 1 - \left(1 - \frac {x^2}{2} + O(x^4)\right)$$

and $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$. Applying this to the first limit gives

$$n^3 \left(1 - \cos \frac 1 n\right) \sin \frac 1 n = n^3 \left(\frac 1 {2n^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)\left(\frac 1 n + O\left(\frac 1 {n^3}\right)\right) = \frac 1 2 + O\left(\frac 1 n\right)$$

Comment: So I can use tayloring to solve for limits of sequences? I didnt know that this would hold. Thanks!